# Can't filter data from database using getSelect()->where() Magento 2

Tags: magento, grid, admin, magento2

I am currently working with magento 2.2.1 and I am having a weird problem. I am trying to get a set of data from database and display it on admin grid. I want to take records for a specific agent ID so i have a variable that has the value of the agent id. When i pass this variable as parameter to`$this->collection->getSelect()->where('agent_id = ?', $this->givenAgentId);` it wont display anything but if i replace $this->givenAgentId with it's value, for example with 4, it works perfectly!

This is my class:

```
<?php
namespace vendor\plugin\Ui\Component\Listing\DataProviders\Atisstats\Coupons;

use \vendor\plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Coupons\CollectionFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Listing extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider {

protected $_registry;

protected $givenAgentId = 0;

public function __construct(
    Registry $registry,
    $name,
    $primaryFieldName,
    $requestFieldName,
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    array $meta = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);

    $this->_registry = $registry;

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $select = $connection->select()
        ->from(
            ['amasty_perm_dealer'],
            ['user_id']
        );
    $data = $connection->fetchAll($select);

    foreach ($data as $dealerId) {
        if ($dealerId['user_id'] == $this->_registry->registry('admin_session_id')) {
            $this->givenAgentId = intval($this->_registry->registry('admin_session_id'));
        }
    }

    if ($this->givenAgentId != 0) {
        $this->collection->getSelect()->where('agent_id = ?', $this->givenAgentId);
    } else {
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
    }

}
```

}

I have stuck here for hours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this problem! First of all it was Registry class causing the problem so I used

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resourceUserId = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session');
```

to get the user id from session and used it below to check the user! For some reason the registry object was modifying the variable holding the current users id!
I post the answer just in case someone get stuck with this kind of problem !